# Change encoding of MATLAB help browser to UTF-8?

Tags: matlab, encoding

Following the accepted answer given in [this link](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/280988-how-do-i-get-my-matlab-editor-to-read-utf-8-characters-utf-8-characters-in-blank-squares-in-editors), I set my MATLAB encoding to UTF-8. It works fine for the MATLAB editor, correctly showing characters including **Chinese**. However, when I open a function in the **help browser** to view the function help comments, it fails.

*How to change the encoding of MATLAB help browser to UTF-8?*

My system: **Windows 10, Simplified Chinese**

Comment: I suggest contacting Mathworks